# overloading method with different return type with namespace not reference in another project consuming it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, overloading, msxml

Project A has few overloaded methods to return XMLNode and MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode with but different parameters as follows

```
static public XmlNode XMLNewChildNode(XmlNode oParent, string sName)
    {
        ...
        return xmlNode;
    }
```

and

```
static public MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode XMLNewChildNode(MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode oParent, string sName)
    {
        ...
        return ixmldomnode;
    }
```

Project B doesn't have reference to interop.MSXML2.dll and when I consude XMLNewChildNode() to return XMLNode, I get compile error.

```
XmlNode oNode = XMLHelper.XMLNewChildNode2((XmlNode)oDoc, UCMCommonPTLIndep.gsUCP_DDT_ROOT_NODE);
```

Error: `The type 'MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Interop.MSXML2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=98ec9cb7b15b7e98'.`

Is not possible to have overloads like this in c#? Am I missing somthing?

Comment: Projects don't have overloaded methods, classes do. Can you post the relevant parts of XmlHelper? Including full namespace etc.

Comment: You're missing a reference to `Interop.MSXML2` in project B, exactly as the compiler says...

Comment: @JonSkeet: we want to remove `Interop.MSXML2` from Project B.

Comment: You can't if you use project A you have a dependency to interop.MSXML2.

Comment: @user3410239: Then you can't use any part of the public api of project A which refers to it, basically. (I think you'd be over if you weren't calling any overloads...)

Comment: @PhilipStuyck but if I rename these methods, it works fine. I am curious why the overloading doesn't work..

Comment: @user, that is because if you call one method that is overloaded, you pull in all the methods overloads.

Comment: When you call an overloaded method, the compiler has to perform overload resolution. It can't do that if it doesn't recognize the types in some of those overloads.

Comment: @JLRishe nicely formulated I meant exactly that. +1

Comment: To solve issues like this I tend to use interface assemblies. Assemblies that contain only interfaces and that are implemented elsewhere. A dependency to an interface assembly is not so bad. Make sure all interfaces are solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is not possible to have overloads like this in c#?"

Clearly it is, as long as the consumers of those overloads have the needed references.

You should be able to resolve this by giving the methods different names, but preferably, you should put the methods in different classes. This would also resolve your issue:

```
public static class XmlNodeHelper
{
    static public XmlNode XMLNewChildNode(XmlNode oParent, string sName)
    {
        ...
        return xmlNode;
    }
}

public static class MSXMLHelper
{
    static public MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode XMLNewChildNode(MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode oParent, string sName)
    {
        ...
        return ixmldomnode;
    }
}
```